# Exception thrown while accessing the option page from another package

Tags: c#, visual-studio

IN Visual Studio 2022, I created a custom dialog page in Tools->Option page and need to access this from another vs package which is dependent on each other. I follow this
[link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/options-and-options-pages?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#accessing-options-pages-from-another-vspackage) to achieve this.
Image of my snippet to retrieve option page value:- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcLwK.png)

But the exception is thrown in dte.get properties method. It occurs only if my page name includes a dot character, such as “.”
eg:-

dte.get_Properties(“CategoryName”, “ASP.NET Core”); -Throws exception
dte.get_Properties(“CategoryName”, “ASPNET Core”); -Working Fine

I tried this solution  [[https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Exception-thrown-access-option-page-from/10099451](https://stackoverflow.com)],but the issue is not resolved. Please suggest a valid solution to resolve this issue.